# Is there a way to get source maps with ts.transform (TypeScript Compiler API)?

Tags: source-maps, typescript-compiler-api

The TypeScript Compiler API has multiple ways of transforming files:

- create a transpiler host and implement `getCustomTransformers`. This has source map support
- use `ts.transform`. This does not seem to have source map support.

For various reasons, `ts.transform()` is a lot easier to use in this particular situation.

How can I get source maps when using `ts.transform()`?

Comment: Have you found the solution ?

Comment: still cant find an answer :(